# How to solve "Error: can't open elf64 for reading: No such file or directory"

Tags: c, ubuntu, libvpx

I was compiling libvpx-1.7.0 on ubuntu-20.04
the configure command is:

```
./configure --disable-vp8 --enable-vp9 --enable-libyuv --target=x86_64-linux-gcc --enable-debug --disable-install-docs --log=yes --enable-internal-stats --disable-unit-tests --disable-docs --disable-tools --enable-webm-io --disable-optimizations
```

the make command is:

```
make
```

then I an error:

```
 [AS] vpx_ports/emms_mmx.asm.o
Assembler messages:
Error: can't open elf64 for reading: No such file or directory
vpx_ports/emms_mmx.asm:2: Error: no such instruction: `copyright (c) 2010 The WebM project authors. All Rights Reserved.'
vpx_ports/emms_mmx.asm:4: Error: no such instruction: `use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license'
vpx_ports/emms_mmx.asm:5: Error: no such instruction: `that can be found in the LICENSE file in the root of the source'
vpx_ports/emms_mmx.asm:6: Error: no such instruction: `tree. An additional intellectual property rights grant can be found'
vpx_ports/emms_mmx.asm:7: Error: junk `file PATENTS.  All contributing project authors may' after expression
vpx_ports/emms_mmx.asm:7: Error: operand size mismatch for `in'
vpx_ports/emms_mmx.asm:8: Error: no such instruction: `be found in the AUTHORS file in the root of the source tree.'
vpx_ports/emms_mmx.asm:12: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `%'
vpx_ports/emms_mmx.asm:14: Error: no such instruction: `section .text'
vpx_ports/emms_mmx.asm:15: Error: invalid character '(' in mnemonic
vpx_ports/emms_mmx.asm:16: Error: invalid character '(' in mnemonic
```

What can I do to solve the problem?

I can compile libvpx and run vpxdec last night, at first I didn't add the configure option "--disable-optimizations". After the first time I add "--disable-optimizations" I can't compile it any more, no matter whether "--disable-optimizations" is used.

Comment: I suspect a missing build depends.  Suggest you run strace make >& make.log, then inspect it for elf64 to see what file it's trying to open.  The error output suggest the .asm files is using an incorrect format (malformed? assembler doesn't understand input input file)?  You may want to review vpx_ports/emms_mmx.asm to see if it looks reasoanble.

Comment: @AllanWind Thanks for your suggestion. I finally find out that I was using a wrong assembler. Now I have solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

May be there were something that changed my environment variant. I finally find out that I was using a wrong assembler. Just adding the option "--as=yasm" at configure command can fix the error.

Comment: Though I don't understand how this works. But `--as=yasm` does solve my problem. Thanks man.